# Configure Ember's back-end to communicate with a RESTful service

Tags: web-services, rest, ember.js, ember-data

There seems to be a lot of discussion on SO (e.g. these questions: [A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29947123/320399), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27736272/320399), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26021042/320399), [D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12729771/320399)) and other sites (e.g the [Ember docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_url-host)) about configuring Ember to allow cross-origin requests.  That's all fine and well, but I'd rather have Ember's back-end do the work of communicating with a remote service (Ember's server-side components to make the request, rather than the user's browser).  Is this documented?  Can someone provide an example?

Comment: ember has no server-side components

Comment: @adammokan See my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would find it easy to modify the HTTP server backing the `ember serve` command.  Instead, I used the `--proxy` flag from Ember's CLI.  It allows you to use remote services to provide data.

For this to work, let's assume a remote server `foo.com:3000` provides JSON data at the path `/resource`.  Configure a controller to GET the data like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function getRemoteResource(store){
  var dfd = Ember.$.Deferred();

  Ember.$.ajax('/resource')
  .done(function(data){
    store.createRecord('model', data);
    dfd.resolve();
  })
  .fail(function(err){
    dfd.reject(new Error("An error occurred getting data.", err));
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    getResource:function(){
      var dataStore = this.store;
      return getRemoteResource(dataStore);
    }
  }
});
```

Use a template like this to invoke the controller's action:

```
<h2>Remote data example</h2>

<button class="my-button" {{action 'getResource' }}>
  Get resource
</button>
```

Assuming your code is on host `bar.com`, start ember like this : `ember serve --proxy http://foo.com:3000`.  Then, open your browser to the appropriate page that loads the template (somewhere like `http://bar.com:4200/index`) , click the button and see that remote data is loaded.